# Graphical tool for shortest path problem?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I need Graphical tool to display and edit the data of shortest path problem(or other Graph Theory problem), so anybody knows this tool?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [applet](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~jstewart/270/9798s/Laffra/DijkstraApplet.html) I could find which illustrates Shortest Path problem. Select All items from the drop down, click example and step through it.